# Conjecture about $A f(x) = f(g(x)) + f(h(x))$

Tags: functional-equations

Let a given real $A$ satisfy $0 < A < 2$.

Conjecture :

For any real entire nonconstant $f(x)$ there exist real entire $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ such that

$A f(x) = f(g(x)) + f(h(x))$

or

$ A f(x) = f(g(x)) - f(h(x))$

is satisfied.

Is this true ?

If its true , then how to compute $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ efficiently ?

**edit**

I changed the question due to HansEnglers comment.
Basically I assumed the equations to hold on a real interval but because of analytic continuation the equation must hold everywhere.

**edit**

**edit 2**

I added the condition that $f(x)$ needs to be a nonconstant function.
( I am tempted to wonder if I need to say nonpolynomial )

This edit is thanks to the comment of user43208.

**edit 2**

Comment: The tag complex analysis was removed.
No big deal but I wonder :
Does asking questions about real-entire functions not justify the tag of complex analysis ?
Afterall entire functions are a subject of complex analysis.

Comment: Wouldn't this then follow on all $\mathbb{R}$, by analytic continuation? Or do you mean to say $\forall x \, Af(x) = f(g(x)) + f(h(x)) \, \vee \, Af(x) = f(g(x)) - f(h(x))$?

Comment: @HansEngler well suppose $g$ is something like $x^2 + 1$ and $h$ is something like $x^6 + 1$. If $x>0$ implies $f(x) > 1$ then I think it does not follow from analytic continuation  because of problems with range and domain ...
Im not sure though.

Comment: Hmm I think Hans is correct. by analytic continuation it must follow on all of R.

Comment: When you use "entire" to describe a function on reals, do you mean "[real analytic](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Real_analytic_function)"?

Answer (score 1):

The conjecture is false. Consider $ A = 1 $ and $ f ( x ) = \frac 1 2 \left ( 1 + \frac 1 { 1 + x ^ 2 } \right ) $, both satisfying the requirements of the problem. for any $ x \in \mathbb R $ we have $ \frac 1 2 < f ( x ) \le 1 $. Therefore for any $ y , z \in \mathbb R $ we have $ f ( y ) + f ( z ) > 1 $ and $ f ( y ) - f ( z ) < \frac 1 2 $. This means that $ A f ( x ) = f ( y ) + f ( z ) $ and $ A f ( x ) = f ( y ) - f ( z ) $ never happen for any $ x , y , z \in \mathbb R $.